# How do you control the speed of rotation?

Tags: animation

Heyo, I've been using Blender for about a year now. I came from Maya and C4d. I have a problem that seems like it should have a simple answer, but I can't find it. How do you control the REVOLUTIONS of something rotating? When I try to set keys from 0 to 360 degrees, it works fine, but if I THEN add a 3rd key frame, so that the object slows down back to 0 degrees, from 360 degrees, the object starts to spin backwards halfway through the animation. I just want it to start spinning, get faster, and then slow down. What am i doing wrong? Is this something that con only done in the NLA? If so how?

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: Hit "N" to call the right side panel and type in directly the rotation what you want for example (0;0;720) then hover the mouse above the rotation panel and hit I to animate the rotation's value.

Comment: Thanks FFeller.  I got it to work, I had to add a keyframe at every second, each time adding 360 degrees in the positive.  Once I had that, i was then able to slow down the rotation by dragging out the final keyframe.  Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: If you found solution please create an answer for your question and mark the answer as solved. Like now people searching for similar issue don't know it has solution. If you don't want to help others you can consider to delete your question if you don't see it as useful.